# Emitting the "Side Outputs" and "process output" in single sink with different path

Tags: apache-flink

How to emit the "Side Outputs"  and "process output" using single sink. Here, in this case, both output needs emit to single sink and based on the tag folder path differs

Eg

```
OutputTag<String> outputTag = new OutputTag<String>("side-output") {};    
SingleOutputStreamOperator<String> mainDataStream = source.process(new ProcessFunction<String, String>() {
    @Override
    public void processElement(String value, Context ctx, Collector<String> out) {
        try {
             builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(value)));
             out.collect(value);
        } catch (SAXException | IOException e) {
             ctx.output(outputTag, value);
        }
    }
});
DataStream<String> sideOutputStream = mainDataStream.getSideOutput(outputTag);
```

Is there any other better solution? Just worried about performance

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a single sink, you can add an attribute into your output format and use the attribute to identify the data source in the single sink.

You can also construct two sinks with different parameters to receive data from different sources. In my opinion, without considering the database you use, this kind of multi-thread way has better performance.

Comment: I have use BucketingSink(S3). Do have any pointer how to set attributes on this

Comment: BucketSink only supports one target path. Therefore, you can only sink data into one destination with one sink class instance. You can try the second way if you don't mind two sink class instances, or you can create your own s3 sink instead of BucketSink, which is not worth it from my perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Flink's [BucketingSink](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/fs/bucketing/BucketingSink.html) can use a [Bucketer](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/fs/bucketing/Bucketer.html) to determine which sub-directory inside of the base directory will be used. So you can use this to set the sub-directory based on an attribute in your record being written.

As far as using a single sink, since both the main output and the side output of your function are String objects (same type), you can `mainDataStream.union(sideOutputStream)` the two streams together before outputting the result.